# is there a way of changing the text of a button clicked based on the id

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const [toFollow, setToFollow] = useState('follow')

const follow = (user_id) => {
        users && users.map(user => {
                if(user.user_id !== user_id){
                  setToFollow('following')
                }   
            })  
  }
```

this is the array. the problem is that the entire follow prop changes when i just want only the id clicked to change

```
  <FlatList
      style={{marginBottom: 60}}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}
      data={users && users}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <UserFollowCard
        p_image={item.profile_image}
        name={item.name_of_user}
        username={item.username}
        textToFollow={toFollow}
        follow = {() => follow(item.user_id)}
      />
          )}
           keyExtractor={item => item.user_id}
   />

t

this is the flatlist rendering the array with the component
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume users is a state, and I can modify users with setUsers.

```
const follow = (user_id) => {
         setUsers(users.map(user => user.id === user_id ? { ...user, follow: !user.follow } : user ))
}
```

I first create an additional key in the users object, and set it to toggle true/false.

Then in your component.

```
  <UserFollowCard
    p_image={item.profile_image}
    name={item.name_of_user}
    username={item.username}
    textToFollow={item.follow ? "I am following" : "I am not following"}
    follow = {() => follow(item.user_id)}
  />
```

I use tenary operator to check if follow is true, and display different message.

You also need to set extraData={users} so it gets re-rendered

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about the question. You can change the button title on the basis of conditions. I have written some code, Here is [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-cdn-300q5?file=/src/App.js).
Instead of Button, u can use TouchableOpacity.